# fastapi jwt authentication issue

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi, middleware, uvicorn

I am new to Python. I have an app that is built in Django and it has user authentication. once any user logs in this app returns a jwt token.

so now I want to create another app with fastAPI which will use the same token for validate the users.

Project file structure

```
project/
│
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── middleware.py
└── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

so I want to use a middleware that will validate all the protected routes. from frontend i will add that token in header Authorization key "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0.bqxXg9VwcbXKoiWtp-osd0WKPX307RjcN7EuXbdq-CE" like this

so my middleware will validate all the API call

**below is my main.py code sample**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.middleware import AuthMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

# Apply middleware
app.add_middleware(AuthMiddleware)


@app.get("/protected")
async def protected_route():
    return {"message": "This is a protected route"}
```

**my middleware file code sample**

```
import json
import logging
import requests


from starlette.requests import Request
from typing import Callable, Coroutine, Any
from starlette.responses import Response, JSONResponse
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware


logger = logging.getLogger("CustomMiddleware")


def error_response(error_msg: str, status_code: int) -> JSONResponse:
    logger.error(error_msg)
    return JSONResponse(
        content={"error": {"message": error_msg}},
        status_code=status_code,
    )


def validate_token(token: str) -> bool:
    jwks_uri = f"https://dev-3x4z3x4z.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json" # Replace with your Auth0 domain

    jwks = json.loads(requests.get(jwks_uri).text)
    header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)

    signing_key = None
    for key in jwks["keys"]:
        if key["kid"] == header["kid"]:
            signing_key = jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(key))
            break

    if not signing_key:
        return False

    try:
        jwt.decode(
            token,
            signing_key,
            algorithms=["RS256"],
        )
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Token validation failed: {e}")
        return False


class AuthMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(
        self,
        request: Request,
        call_next: Callable[[Request], Coroutine[Any, Any, Response]],
    ) -> Response:
        try:
            if "Authorization" not in request.headers:
                return error_response("Unauthorized", 401)
            token_header = request.headers["Authorization"]
            if token_header.startswith("Bearer "):
                token = token_header.split("Bearer ")[-1]
                if not validate_token(token):
                    return error_response("Unauthorized", 401)
            else:
                return error_response("Token should begin with Bearer", 400)
        except Exception as e:
            return error_response(f"{e}", 400)
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
```

Comment: What's your question? (and a tip; doing a http request every time you want to validate a token means that you're going to effectively query the other API every time someone makes a request to your API; you're also making sync requests in an async endpoint, which means your fastapi instance will lock up while that takes place, dropping the amount of requests you can handle severely. Fetch the keys on startup if necessary, or add them in a config file instead.